# Is there a way I can see the payout history in appstore connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

Is there a way to see the payout history in appstore connect? I have tried looking in financial reports, but I can only get reports per month.

Answer (score 1):

From Stack Overflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996656/itunes-connect-check-total-sales

> From the Apple User Guide for the Financial Reports (available at bottom of iTunes Connect page):
>
> > We do not store or regenerate the data after the periods have expired
> >     (14 rolling days and 13 rolling weeks); you will need to download and
> >     store this data on a regular basis if you intend to use it in the
> >     future.

Comment: Hmm. That does not make sense since I can actually see financial reports for every month back to 2014 when I launched my first app. But I had to step through every month to see when Apple had made payouts, which in my case wasn't that frequent - unfortunately :D But thanks for your answer!